# How to take an arbitrary sequence of bits from a byte array and turn it into an integer in Python?

Tags: python, byte

I am looking for a python equivalent of https://www.npmjs.com/package/bit-sequence.

That is to say, I need a function which takes some 'bytes', some 'start' value corresponding to an integer bit index to start extraction (not byte index), and some 'length' value to correspond to the amount of bits to extract from the bytes array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an answer, with the example from the page you linked:

```
def bitSequence(bytes, start, length):
    
    # Converting the bytes array into one long bit string
    binstring = "".join([bin(byte)[2:].zfill(8) for byte in bytes])
    
    # Converting the required part of the bitstring to a base 10 int
    ret_byte = int("0b"+binstring[start:start+length], 2)

    return  ret_byte

example=[ 0b00010101, 0b10101000, 0b00000000, 0b00000000 ]
print(bitSequence(example , 7, 11))
1696
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that solves your problem, for more information about bit manipulation in python take a look at this link ->https://realpython.com/python-bitwise-operators/#bit-strings-in-python

```
def bytes_extraction(bytes, start, length):
    bytes = bin(bytes)
    result = bytes[start:start+length]
    result = int(result, 2)
    return  result

bits = 0b101010 
response = bytes_extraction(bytes=bits , start=2, length=4)
print(response)
```

Comment: bytes_extraction(bits, 0, 2) will return the "0b" prefix; you should fix that; furthermore, it seems the function should operate on an array of bytes